# Migrate from DynamoDB to Global DDB with sort key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We have a dynamo DB table with no sort key, only partition key (ConsumerId). Now we have new requirements:

1. convert this to a global dynamo DB table. (we are moving to multi-region)
2. query data within a date range satisfying a condition (STATUS = approved/rejected/pending). (Query results be fetched by lambda and passed to UI where user can see his search results in a dashboard.)

Right now dynamo is unable to scan all APPROVED cases due to huge amount of data within the required time. So we are planning:

1. export data to s3.
2. create a new global table with sort key and import data from s3.

Will this approach work ? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Exporting data to S3 and importing to a new table will work, so long as your data has a sort key value for all items.

However, having `ConsumerId` as partition key and status#date as sort key won't fulfill your access pattern of "get all items in a date range". To effectively query you'll need date or status as the partition key.

Comment: Makes sense for point 2. But for point 1: that is the issue: currently the data items doesn't have a sort key.

Comment: That's also fine, if the sort key value is not already an attribute in the table then you can run an ETL job to add one on the data as it sits on S3

Comment: It would be really great if you could provide any reference/ doc regarding the Glue job.

Comment: The Glue docs provide you exactly what you need to get started, but you'll need to know some pyspark or scala in order to transform the data how you want to shape it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb

Comment: Hey, so I tried to export data from dynamo to an S3 and import to a global table with sort key defined and it worked well without changing data in S3.
But now we have this requirement to put the data to particular folders in S3 depending upon the MONTH when the data was uploaded to dynamo DB. (All docs uploaded in DDB during NOV gets exported to a folder called NOV in S3.) 
So for this, will I need a glue job - to extract all datas uploaded only during a particular month frm DDB and import to S3?

Comment: You can do an IncrementalExport once per month. And when it completes simply do an `aws s3 cp` command to copy the folder to the desired destination.

Comment: We are going to do this with a dynamo table having already 75k + records spanning over 8months. This is one time thing. From later on, a basic export will serve the need.

Comment: In that case to split the data up by month, you'll have to use Glue like you said.